# AWS SNS for push notifications

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using AWS to send push notifications.

When I send the notification, the message is received, but the application doesnt get a number put against it. I was expecting a "1" to show on the app icon.

Here is the code I use to send the notification.

```
$snsmessage = $sns->publish(
array(
'TargetArn' => $endpoint,
'MessageStructure' => 'json',
'Message' => json_encode(array(
    'APNS' => json_encode(array(
        'aps' => array(
            'alert' => "message to send goes here",
            'badge'=>'1',
            'sound'=>'default'
        )
    ))

))
)

);
```

What do i need to do to get the number to show on the app?

Comment: Do you receive the message in the notification center?

Comment: yes the message is received just fine, it just doesnt show the "1" badge next to the app.

Comment: Is your app in the foreground, background or terminated when the notification is delivered?

Comment: Its in the background, if it is in the foreground, I can understand it not been there, but when its in the background, I can see the notification turn up, but it never adds a number to the icon.